# modifying the value of a complex type in a C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand why using `operator[]` on `unordered_map` in C++ gives me different results when I attempt to modify the value using `[]` directly vs. store the value in a temporary object. Here's an example:

```
unordered_map<int,vector<int>> map;
map.emplace(0, vector<int>(10, 1) );

map[0][0] = 2; // this works
cerr << map[0][0] << endl; // prints out 2 - as expected

auto foo = map[0];
foo[1] = 3; // this does not work -- the value in map[0][1] is still 1
cerr << map[0][1] << endl; // prints out 1, expected: 3
```

My understanding was that `map[0]` should return the reference to the associated value, not its copy, but it seems that `foo` is a copy since changes to `foo` are transient. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use `auto` carelessly.

Comment: To continue @KerrekSB's comment (I think), it's because `auto foo = map[0];` creates a *copy* of the value in the map, so modifying the copy won't affect the value within the map. If you want to use `auto`, use `auto &foo=...`.

Comment: Replacing `auto` w/ `vector<int>` produces the same result (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) )

Comment: Yes, that makes a copy as well. Just like `int a = b` will make a copy. Changing `a` doesn't change `b`.

Comment: I think the subtlety I was missing was that `map[0][0]` does not erase the reference specifier while using assignment `=` des (whether using `auto` or the explicit type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

construct a new variable (a copy) foo from the return type of map[0]:

```
auto foo = map[0];
```

make foo's type be exactly what map[0] returned, even if it's a reference:

```
decltype(auto) foo = map[0];
```

make a reference to the type that results from removing any reference specifier from the return type of map[0]:

```
auto& foo = map[0];
```

make a const reference to the type that results from removing any reference specifier and const specifier from the return type of map[0]:

```
auto const& foo = map[0];
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer -- thank you! I should pay more attention to `CopyConstructible` in docs on `operator[]` :)

Answer (score 0):

> map[0] should return the reference to the associated value

It does.

The problem is literally what you wrote:

You store the value in a temporary object, that is, in a copy (`auto`!) and not in a *reference*. Modifying the copy won't change the original object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `foo` to be a copy of `map[0]`, you want it to *refer* to `map[0]`.

So, make `foo` a reference:

```
auto& foo = map[0];
    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment `=` operator for `vector<T>` type will produce a copy of the value being assigned. That's what happens in `auto foo = map[0];` line. `foo` is a copy. [**Docs**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/).

You have several options to go:

1. `map[0][1] = 3`
2. `vector<int> &foo = map[0]` and `foo[1] = 3` after.
3. `vector<int> *foo = &map[0]` and `(*foo)[1] = 3` after.